# How to add a comma before keywords in R?

Tags: r, regex, data-manipulation

I currently have a dataframe/vector of cities that have words at the end that start with any of the following: Util, Municipal, Police, Water, or a # at the end.

How to go from:

| Col |
| --- |
| City of Fake Municipal Court |
| City of Pretend Water Utility |
| City of Not Real Police Department |
| Fraud Hill Utility |
| El Imagined 344th District Court |

To this:

| Col |
| --- |
| City of Fake, TX Municipal Court |
| City of Pretend, TX Water Utility |
| City of Not Real, TX Police Department |
| Fraud Hill, TX Utility |
| El Imagined, TX 344th District Court |

The current code I have is:

```
DATA %>%
  mutate(col = str_replace(col, "(?i)(?>=(UTIL | MUNICIPAL | Police | Water | ^([0-9]+)")),?\\s", ", TX"))
```

I *think* that every keyword is included correctly in this expression. What I'm definitely not sure of is if I'm getting the numbers wrong.

Comment: Correction: I'm not getting the keywords right, either.

Comment: Try `(?i)\\s*\\b(util(?:ity)?|MUNICIPAL|Police|Water|[0-9]+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?)(?:,?\\s)?`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This worked! I changed 'ity' to 'ities'. Do you mind explaining what util(?:ity) is doing, however?

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
x <- c("City of Fake Municipal Court", "City of Pretend Water Utility","City of Not Real Police Department","Fraud Hill Utility","El Imagined 344th District Court")
regex <- "(?i)\\s*\\b(util(?:it(?:y|ies))?|MUNICIPAL|Police|Water|[0-9]+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?)(?:,?\\s)?"
trimws(sub(regex, ", TX ", x, perl=TRUE))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FH18SU/1) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/blgfa4). Note `sub` will only replace the first occurrence, and `perl=TRUE` is required for the PCRE pattern to work with `sub`.

*Pattern details*:

- `(?i)` - the pattern is case insensitive
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(util(?:it(?:y|ies))?|MUNICIPAL|Police|Water|[0-9]+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?)` - Group 1: either `util` followed with an optional `it` that is followed with either `y` or `ies`, or `MUNICIPAL`, or `Police`, or `Water`, or one or more digits followed optionally by `st`, `r` or `n` and then `d`, or `th`
- `(?:,?\s)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching one or zero occurrences of an optional comma and then a whitespace char.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
# Create a dataframe with the given data
df <- data.frame(
  Col = c(
    "City of Fake Municipal Court",
    "City of Pretend Water Utility",
    "City of Not Real Police Department",
    "Fraud Hill Utility",
    "El Imagined 344th District Court"
  )
)
# Define a regular expression pattern
regex_pattern <- "(?i)\\b(util(?:it(?:y|ies))?|MUNICIPAL|Police|Water|[0-9]+(?:st|[rn]d|th)?)(?:,?\\s)?"

# Use mutate to modify the Col column
df <- df %>%
  mutate(Col = str_replace_all(Col, regex_pattern, ", TX \\1"))

# Display the modified dataframe
print(df)
```

Modified data fram will given as

```
Col
1       City of Fake , TX MunicipalCourt
2 City of Pretend , TX Water, TX Utility
3 City of Not Real , TX PoliceDepartment
4                Fraud Hill , TX Utility
5   El Imagined , TX 344thDistrict Court
```

1. (?i) makes the regular expression case-insensitive, so it matches
   both uppercase and lowercase variations of the keywords.
2. \b matches a word boundary, ensuring that we only match whole
   words.
3. util(?:it(?:y|ies))? matches variations of "util," including "utility" and "utilities" if they exist.
4. | is the alternation operator, allowing us to match any of the
   specified keywords.
5. Police|Water matches "Police" or "Water." [0-9]+(?:st|[rn]d|th)? matches numbers with possible "st," "nd," or "th" suffixes (e.g.,"344th").
6. (?:,?\s)? matches an optional comma followed by optional whitespa